# FluidPages/Flux configuration not inherited to child pages

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid, fedext

I've the following page template:

```xml
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
     xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
     xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers"
     xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers">

    <f:layout name="Page"/>

    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="standard">
            <flux:field.input name="settings.claim1" />
            <flux:field.input name="settings.claim2" />
            <flux:field.inline.fal name="settings.stageImage" maxItems="1" minItems="0" />
        </flux:form>
        <flux:grid>
            <!-- Edit this grid to change the "backend layout" structure -->
            <flux:grid.row>
                <flux:grid.column colPos="0" name="main"/>
            </flux:grid.row>
        </flux:grid>
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="Main">
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <f:render partial="Header" section="Content"/>
            <f:render partial="Stage" section="Content" arguments="{_all}" />
            <f:render partial="Breadcrumb" section="Content"/>
            <v:content.render column="0"/>
        </div>
    </f:section>
</div>
```

It's the only one I have and only selected on my root page. All other pages inherit that template .

What do I have to do that the values of the configuration are inherited to child pages? I already tried inherit="true" for the fields as suggested in the ViewHelper reference, but I don't know what to do with the information "*if inheritance is enabled by the ConfigurationProvider*".

I'm using T3 7.6 and latest TER versions of Flux, Fluidpages etc.

Answer (score 0):

When editing your root page, did you set the backend layout of the subpages to fluidpages?

[image: Set backend layout to fluidpages in layout tab]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... have been ill since.
Yes, I have set the suggested setting. I also have both layouts checked under "Page Layouts"